# Is the execution speed of the 'transferIn()' function about 0.16s?

Tags: webusb

It receives 2048 bytes from one **transferIn** function as bulk transfer.
It takes 0.16s to execute one function.
This means it takes more than 80s to get 1mb.
What should I do to speed this up on my JavaScript code using WebUSB? Or is there no way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the time it actually takes for the data to be transferred a single call to `transferIn()` has to do a lot of work to set up the host to receive data from the device. Even assuming there was zero delay introduced by the web browser and operating system the USB only provides transfer opportunities every 1ms (for full-speed devices) or 125us (for high-speed devices). The tricks for increasing your data transfer rate are:

1. Submit `transferIn()` calls with buffers much larger than the endpoint's packet size. This trades latency for throughput. The transfer won't complete until the buffer is full or a short packet is received but the host controller won't waste time waiting around for the operating system to ask it to ask the device for more data.
2. Submit multiple `transferIn()` calls in parallel. This adds more overhead but solves the latency problem by reporting transfer completion at higher granularity. This technique is commonly used for endpoints that deliver events. Keeping at least two transfers in flight at once guarantees that the next event will be delivered immediately rather than having to wait until a new transfer request is set up after the first event is processed.

This advice also applies for `transferOut()`.

Comment: The first method of your grateful advice has already been tried, and the second solution is in the middle of experimenting in consultation with the device side developer. It sends the command through transferOut every 1msec, and it receives and processes the result using web worker. This process speeded up about 10 times faster. I have not yet verified the integrity of the data, but if I have any further questions, I will post it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @reilly-grant I tried method 2, submitting 3 * `transferIn()` calls in parallel to receive 64 byte or shorter packets. But the packets occasionally arrive in my application in the wrong order. I did not notice this until Chrome 87.

Comment: @James Can you file an issue report about that on crbug.com? Please tag it with the Blink>USB component and include sample code.

Comment: @reilly-grant Thank you, I have submitted: Issue 1153647 with source code. I did not see how I could tag it or fill OS: Windows 10.