# WebUSB/transferIn: how to reuse memory?

Tags: javascript, webusb

[transferIn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USBDevice/transferIn) seems allocate memory each function call, is there any way to reuse it?

My goal is to get lots of data from device, with a dedicated web worker and [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54337037/4818351), performance still not good enough. From performance tab in dev tools, found that the delayed is caused by GC.

Answer (score 0):

Add a comment to https://github.com/WICG/webusb/issues/217 with your observations. The one thing I'm unsure of is whether just reducing buffer allocations will help since there are still other small allocations involved in calling those methods.